# Check if Visual C++ 2010 is installed - No Work

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, registry

For my program, I want it to check if Visual C++ is already installed and from a little bit of Googling, I can check if they are installed by checking the registry key as stated here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/05/10008146.aspx

The thing is, when I actually run the program, nothing happens. I tried running it as an Admin, nothing still happens. Here is my code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class Form1
    Public Sub Form1_Load()
        Dim regKey As RegistryKey
        regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x64", True)
        If Not regKey Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Found")
        Else
            MsgBox("Not Found")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Im not sure if either im typing it right or what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MSDN link you should be reading from the Local Machine key, not the Current User key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x64]
```

You should try changing the `regKey` line in your code as follows:

```
regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE...
' change this --> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

EDIT - regarding your form not doing anything: Your `Form1_Load` function is never being called because it doesn't have the right signature. Change your `Form1_Load` function signature to this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    Dim regKey As RegistryKey
    ...
```

You might have to run Visual Studio as an admin to be able to read the registry from the Local Machine key.

Comment: I tried doing what you said and changed my code but I still get the same problem that when I run the actual program, nothing happens. The blank form pops up but theres no message box confirming if the registry key exists or not (I even tried running it as admin). Also, if you check the website, they include this: "Installed = 1 (REG_DWORD)" Do I have to include that anywhere in the code?

Comment: @SteveLaster - see the EDIT in my answer above

Comment: chue x, im not sure if u will still see this but if I put my code into another class (not form) and I want to call or use that class, can i do that?

Comment: @SteveLaster - That should definitely be possible.